# adngular 4 sass compiling issue

Tags: angular, sass

Seems that angular doesn't compile sass correctly for components or it does not as expected.

For e.g. this code works well for `app.component.scss`:

```
/* Works well */
.container {
   .header {
      margin-top: 20px;
   }
}
.container {
   .header {
      background-color: black;
   }
}
```

But if I generate `header` component and then add style to the `header.component.scss` that has repetitive selectors for some reason then this will not work!

```
/* Doesn't work */
.container {
   .header {
      padding: 15px;
   }
}
```

Just don't tell me that I shouldn't write such scss code untill it would be recognized by Angular framework correclty. Or explain if I'am doing something wrong :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see, I think you are facing the issue of [**view-encapsulation**](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation)

> 1. Native view encapsulation uses the browser's native shadow DOM
>      implementation (see Shadow DOM on the MDN site) to attach a shadow
>      DOM to the component's host element, and then puts the component
>      view inside that shadow DOM. The component's styles are included
>      within the shadow DOM.
> 2. Emulated view encapsulation (the default) emulates the behavior of
>          shadow DOM by preprocessing (and renaming) the CSS code to
>          effectively scope the CSS to the component's view.
> 3. None means that Angular does no view encapsulation. Angular adds the
>          CSS to the global styles. The scoping rules, isolations, and
>          protections discussed earlier don't apply. This is essentially the
>          same as pasting the component's styles into the HTML.

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Where can I find metadata to set `encapsulation`? :)

Comment: I'am trying to add `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native` to my `@Component({ ...... });` set but an error occurs during the compilation: `Cannot find name 'ViewEncapsulation'.`

Comment: you need to `import ViewEncapsulation` like `import {ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';`

Comment: Sorry, I'am dumb. `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` helped me